# stuck on XML - need to loop through data

Tags: xml, loops, sum

See the below code. I'm trying to sum up all the values for count but I can't figure out how to properly loop through the data. how do I loop thru the element

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import re
from urllib.request import urlopen
#from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl



# Ignore SSL certificate errors
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
#count = 0
url = input('Enter - ')
xml = urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()
#soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

print('Retrieved', len(xml), 'characters')
print(xml.decode())
tree = ET.fromstring(xml)

#counts = tree.findall('comments/comment/count')
counts = tree.findall('.//count')
print('source:',len(counts))
for num in counts :
    print(num)
```

---

how do I loop thru the element

Comment: What's your input XML?

Comment: It saves everyone a minute or two if you tag your question with the name of the programming language you are using.